# Black patches on aloe vera leaves

Tags: plant-health, aloe

Please tell me if this Aloe Vera leaf is healthy. Most of the leaves are green but there are some leaves with these black patches.

Is it safe to consume these leaves raw?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea whether its safe to consume or not, but I wouldn't consume it - it may well be a fungal infection, so if you're sensitive to moulds and fungus infections generally, its probably not a good idea to eat it.

Usual cause of this problem is cultural, that is, the watering regime isn't quite right, more info here

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-aloe-plant-dark-spots-94444.html

Comment: I am eating it raw since many years. Never had any issue at least related to it.

Comment: well I simply meant I wouldn't eat the sap from a leaf with these fungal spots rather than not consuming it generally, which is what you asked about, leaves with black spots