# What are these black round dry spots on my Aloe Vera leaves?

Tags: plant-health, leaves, succulents, aloe

The leaves of my Aloe Vera are covered with black dry regions of round form. They are found on new and old leaves, at the middle and on the edges of the leaves.

What could be the reason? How should I treat it?

It does not look like the question [Black patches on aloe vera leaves](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24965/black-patches-on-aloe-vera-leaves) because in my case the shape of the leaf is changed, the leaves become thinner at the place where the black dot exists.

[image]

Comment: Does the pot it's in have a drainage hole? How often do you water, and how long have you had this plant in the same pot?

Comment: @Bamboo, the same pot for about 1-2 month (changed at the end of the summer). There is a drainage hole but still I water the plant not that much, so water does not go to the dish. Watering it once in a week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is still the same and Bamboo's answer on the other question still holds. Aloes can thrive on very little water. They also hold the water in their leaves, so excess water combined with poor drainage, especially when you water on to the surface can cause logging. This, then causes molding from fungi.

Touch the soil surface with your finger and see how wet it feels. If it is wet, then you need to let it dry. To heal, give this aloe more sun. Move it closer to the sun, or, since summer is over unless you are down under, you can move it out for a few days.

You could remove the black spots very gently using a knife and tweezers, etc. There is no need to discard entire leaves or disturb the plant other wise. In a few days it should be okay. Water sparingly through the cold season.

On an unrelated note, looking at the pot, the plant could use the luxury of a bigger pot. If you choose to do that, make sure the soil is well draining and mulch if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up @SrihariYamanoor answer (if **TLDR**):

1. More sun - closer to window or move it out;
2. Less water;
3. Good drainage - small stones at the bottom of pot;
4. Special soils for succulents - with some sand & stones.

And it took several month to see new leaves without that black spots.